# How to install Nginx Unit on Ubuntu using apt commands?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt

ubuntu 18.04

do this

curl -sL https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | apt-key add -
to configure Unit repository, create the following file named /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unit.list:
deb https://packages.nginx.org/unit/ubuntu/ bionic unit
deb-src https://packages.nginx.org/unit/ubuntu/ bionic unit
apt update
from https://unit.nginx.org/installation/#ubuntu

and get message
repository does not have a Release file

Comment: This is the English StackOverflow. Please ask questions in English here or go to https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
Thank you

Comment: Related: https://www.nginx.com/blog/automating-installation-wordpress-with-nginx-unit-on-ubuntu/